# How to horizontally scroll a inner div with browser scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to make a inner div horizontally scrolleable, but using the browser scrollbar and not that particular div's scrollbar.

One option would be making every other div's position as static and overflowing the wrapper div, but since I'm modiyfing a premade template, I would prefer to be able to do this without changing the layout. In that sense, a JavaScript/jQuery plugin would be nice, but totally not a must.

Here is the code:

```
<title>This is a test</title>
<body>
   <header>
      This is the header.
   </header>
   <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="left-sidebar">
         This is the left sidebar.
      </div>
      <div id="test">
         <div id="content">
            This is the main content.
            <div id="flex">
               <div id="rectangle"></div>
               <div id="rectangle"></div>
               <div id="rectangle"></div>
               <div id="rectangle"></div>
               <div id="rectangle"></div>
               <div id="rectangle"></div>
               <div id="rectangle"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <footer>
      This is the footer. 
   </footer>
</body>
```

Here is the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k6e3sv6v/

Thanks bra

Comment: looks like you applied `overflow-x: scroll` onf `#flex` which is what I would've suggested. So what's the problem?

Comment: a) Just pointing out: static positioning likely does not mean what you thing it means. Everything is statically positioned by default. Very different from fixed positioning, for example. b) What you're asking isn't meant to be done, and any solution involving the actual top-level browser scrollbar will be a total hack. Just don't do it, it will confuse the living soul out of users and will probably destroy the accessibility of the thing.

Comment: @inorganik I applied that on #test, but I need to scroll with the browser scrollbar, as the scrollbar that appears at the bottom.

Comment: @Roope, a) thanks, you're correct! I mean fixed, not static. b) You're correct, but HTML/CSS for GUIs is itself a total hack and I don't care contributing to its ultimate dimissal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot focus BROWSER scrollbar into some div it appears if the whole page is wider than 100% width.

But I think it can be done by putting all other elements around that div as fixed position which won't move over the screen even if the scroll was moved left-right...